# React-native cognito Setting up redirect from facebook and google uri error

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I can't redirect back to my app after trying to login with a federated service.

I followed the AWS-Amplify documentation and am still encountering the issue.

I should end up back on my app signed in as a user.